# Strange assembler output for volatile variable in ARM

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, arm, microcontroller

I had tried the following code on Compile Explorer ([link for code](https://godbolt.org/z/R4-8hS)), compiler ARM gcc 8.3.1 and options -std=gnu++2a -O3

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::uint32_t TP_Address, typename TP_Type = bool>
TP_Type foo(){
    return *reinterpret_cast<TP_Type*>(TP_Address);
};

volatile bool b1;
volatile bool b2;

[[noreturn]] int main(void) {
b1 = foo<0x42000000, volatile bool>();

}
```

and got the following result on the assembler panel

```
main:
        mov     r3, #1107296256
        ldrb    r3, [r3]        @ zero_extendqisi2
        ldr     r2, .L2
        and     r3, r3, #255
        strb    r3, [r2]
.L2:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
b1:
b2:
```

I am failing to understand the reason for the "and operation" with #255 (0xFF). In fact, if the volatile qualifier is taken out, this apparently superfluous "and operation" goes away, but then (as expected) the compiler will optimize the code ignoring that the value is prone to change and leading to incorrect results in subsequent readings.

Given that I know for sure that this specific address holds a bool (ie, the hex value is either 0x0 or 0x1), how can I get rid of the "and operation"?

Comment: My guess is that the `and` is removed by the peephole optimizer, but you can't peephole optimize accesses to volatile data because that could result in optimizing out things which volatility forbids from optimizing out.

Comment: That `and` is totally unnecessary, no matter if your input is just `0` or `1` because it's not `and r3, r3, #1`. As it is, it's only truncating to a byte but the following `strb` only uses a byte so the top bits don't matter. Furthermore the `ldrb` already zeroed the top bits, even the comment says so.

Comment: BTW, the example can be simplified to just `b1 = *(volatile bool*)0x42000000;` no need for complicating with a template. PS: it even works with `char` instead of `bool`.

Comment: Reportedly `clang` works fine. Looks like a missed optimization bug in `gcc`.

Comment: Try typing it as an `int` instead of `bool`, if you can, as in `b1 = foo<0x42000000, volatile int>();`

Comment: try it as a short as well.

Comment: try the unsigned versions as well

Comment: The `and` is necessary if you consider the high 24 bits of r3 which are sign extended by `ldrb`.  Since the code only does a `strb`, it might seem the compiler can get rid of this, but `volatile` will confuse the issue.  Depending on the CPU, it could also stall due to memory dependencies.  You would save one instruction in code size, but probably no timing benefit if it was removed but that will depend on the target CPU.

Comment: @artlessnoise `ldrb` zero extends. `ldrsb` would sign extend, but even if that was used the `and` would still not be necessary.

Comment: @Jester That seems to be correct.  I read some reference that said other wise (or I misread it as I can't find it now), but ARM docs are as you say.

Comment: As @Jester pointed, it seens to be a bug in the optimization. Using gcc version 9.2 I got `uxtb r3, r3`.

Comment: Hi @ErikEidt and old_timer. Tried with uint16_t and uint32_t, there is no additional instruction, even with the volatile qualifier.

Comment: Only when using 8bit types that extra instruction is generated